# When making an API call to a Node.js REST API, how can I view which portion of the code it uses?

Tags: node.js, api, express, debugging

I have a REST API that was built with Node.js and Express.js. When making an API call, how can I view which portion of the code it uses? (without me having to infer it myself by reading the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reddit user [BehindTheMath](https://www.reddit.com/user/BehindTheMath) [pointed me](https://redd.it/tiz0e4) to the following two options: logging and breakpoints.

> Console logging can work, but you'd need to add logging all over the app. Another option is to debug the app, and put breakpoints and see where it stops.